# Force SSL for IIS 6

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, http, ssl-certificate, https

What is the best way to force HTTP requests to HTTPS requests on IIS 6?  For example, I have both a directory and a whole site that I need to force HTTPS on for two different servers.  What is the best or preferred method of accomplishing this?  This will need to redirect requests that come in on HTTP to HTTPS. I was thinking of something along the lines of mod_rewrite from the Linux world.

Note that I already have a certificate installed and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes I have a hard time deciphering exactly what's being asked, but I think this is what you're after:

Right click the web site in question in IIS Manager, click the Directory Security tab, click the Edit button under the Secure communications section, check (enable) the Require secure channel (SSL) check box.

Comment: Will that redirect people coming in from HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: No, it's not a redirect, it's configuring the site so that only SSL connections will be accepted. I kind of thought I was misunderstanding what you were asking.

Comment: That's okay, do you know how to force a redirect?

Comment: I don't, sorry. Someone else will chime in soon enough though.

Comment: Here's a Google search returning several methods for achieving this: https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=redirect+http+to+https+in+iis+6&pbx=1&oq=redirect+http+to+https+in+iis+6&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=920l8056l0l8303l31l15l0l15l15l0l321l2583l2.7.5.1l27l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=8eaad5999fa7e232&biw=1920&bih=940

Answer (score 1):

One method is to include this in your global.asax.cs.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site/47095#47095